# why is the multiprocessing method is slower than single mehod

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need to pull data from a web API for a series of SN,  I implement it in a for-loop function, each loop will spend about 1.5s (due to the query is complex), so I'm trying to use multiple processes to help upgrade the efficiency. but the weird is that the multiple processes will run more time than a single process. I guess the reason is the web api maybe can't support multiple processing, but even though I only run one process use queue method, it still spend double the time of the single process. I can't figure it out.

## initial code

```py
def pull_data(row):
        url_api = '*web api*'
        post_json = {row}
        x = requests.post(url_api, data=post_json)

        return x.json()

for i in range(len(rows)):
        json_f = []

        t_s = time.time()

        json_f = pull_data(rows[0]) # will spend about 1.5s

        t_e = time.time()

        print(f"\nSelect query completed in {format(t_e - t_s, '.2f')}seconds")
```

## multiple processing code

```py
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue

def pull_data(row,q):
        url_api = '*web api*'
        post_json = {row}
        x = requests.post(url_api, data=post_json)
        q.put(x.json())

for i in range(0, len(rows), 3):
        jobs = []
        json_f = []
        q = Queue()

        t_s = time.time()

        if 0 <= i < len(rows):
            p1 = Process(target=pull_data, args=(rows[i], q))
            jobs.append(p1)
            p1.start()

        if 1 <= i + 1 < len(rows):
            p2 = Process(target=pull_data, args=(rows[i + 1], q))
            jobs.append(p2)
            p2.start()

        if 2 <= i + 2 < len(rows):
            p3 = Process(target=pull_data, args=(rows[i + 2], q))
            jobs.append(p3)
            p3.start()

        for proc in jobs:
            proc.join()


        t_e = time.time()

         while not q.empty():
             json_f.append(q.get())


        print(f"\nSelect query completed in {format(t_e - t_s, '.2f')}seconds") 

# total 3 process will run about 6s , even I only run one processing,It also spend about 3s, higher then than initial code.
```

**Thanks @AKX suggestion, that works for me below is this modified**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def threaded_post_requests(rows, max_workers=5):
    with Pool(processes=max_workers) as pool:
        results = pool.map(pull_data, rows)
    return results

def pull_data(row):
        url_api = '*web api*'
        post_json = {row}
        x = requests.post(url_api, data=post_json)

        return [fixture_json, row]


def database_test():
    rows = ['post list']

    results = threaded_post_requests(rows)

    for i in results:
        print("\n", i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    database_test()
```

Comment: Starting a process is an expansive operation, and you start 3 each iteration. This is not how you run task in parallel, you need to start your process outside the loop and give `rows` as parameter.

Comment: @Guy Hi Guy, I'm not familiar with multiple processing, Could you please share with me the best instance? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *best instance*, but have an extensive [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: You're using `multiprocessing` in a pretty suboptimal way – use `multiprocessing.Pool()` and `pool.map()` (and friends) instead.

Comment: @AKX I'm not a code writer and I don't want to struggle too much with this issue，  Your suggestion is direct and helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's no psychic on the platform, so you should profile the code to know what happens.

But creating processes is expensive and you're creating a process per entry, plus you're also paying the cost for serializing and deserializing a structure of unknown complexity to send it over IPC, that's not cheap either.

- since this is entirely IO bound, rather than multiprocessing you should use multithreading or async pools / workers, you should also create a *session* per worker as that allows `requests` to reuse connections
- if you do use multiprocessing, rather than create a process per task by hand you should use a multiprocessing pool to which you submit individual job, while this does not change the cost of serialisation it does amortise the cost of creating processes

Answer (score 1):

[@Masklinn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77712906/139985) is correct, in the general sense.

But in your example there is a major bug that means that your code will run sequentially, not in parallel.  In other words, you incur all of the overheads of IPC ... without any benefit whatsoever.

The problem is that you have put the `join` loop and the loop to process the results *inside* the (outer) loop.  So each outer loop iteration will create and run *one* `Process` and *wait for it to finish*.  In effect, the jobs will run one at a time.  Serially.

The `jobs` array should be declared before the loop, and the code that joins the jobs and accumulates the results should be after the loop.

Comment: Thanks, @Steph, Seems I misunderstood how multiple processing be used, I need to learn it more deeply.